# Python Error The _posixsubprocess module is not being used

Tags: python, multithreading

Hi im running a subprocess with threads trough a python wrapper and I get the following warning when I use the subprocess module.

"The _posixsubprocess module is not being used,  Child process reliability may suffer if your program uses threads."

What dose this mean?
How can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution for me was to do the following:

```
pip uninstall subprocess32
pip install -U subprocess32
```

Intially, I was getting a warning when I tried to import `matplotlib`:

```
Python 2.7.13 (default, May 16 2017, 12:02:12) 
[GCC 6.2.0 20160901] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import matplotlib
/home/methuselah/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/subprocess32.py:472: RuntimeWarning: The _posixsubprocess module is not being used. Child process reliability may suffer if your program uses threads.
  "program uses threads.", RuntimeWarning)
>>>
```

After reinstalling `subprocess32`, the warning goes away:

```
Python 2.7.13 (default, May 16 2017, 12:02:12) 
[GCC 6.2.0 20160901] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import matplotlib
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

check if you can `import _posixsubprocess` manually, subprocess tries to import this in it's code, if it produces an exception this warning is produced.

Comment: No I cannot.. where can i find the module? I have searched for it but cant seam to come across it.

Comment: What OS are you running? Did you get Python from a repository or by building from source?

Comment: Im running linux at the moment the posix module seems to be present on unix and windows.

Comment: @PabloKarlsson: http://code.google.com/p/python-subprocess32/source/browse/_posixsubprocess.c?r=74183385ae8b8fdbc580eca022db3b2d0b787a7b

Comment: This solves the problem. I have now requested an install of the module. Thanks.

Comment: Is the link @avasal posted out of date? I'm seeing a blank Google Code page. How did you solve this problem Pablo Jomer?

Comment: @PabloJomer I am also having this problem, do you remember what you did?

Comment: @Paul Sorry I do not have you tried the answer below.

Comment: @PabloJomer No problem Pabli it was a long time ago haha, I have solved the issue here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46079968/issue-importing-subprocess32/46089996#46089996

Answer (score 3):

unsetting PYTHONHOME has fixed this issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with a tool that was installed with conda. Turned out that there was kind of a conflicting version of subprocess32 that came from pip. Running this did the trick:

```
pip uninstall subprocess32
conda install -c conda-forge subprocess32
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be if you have more than a version of Python in use.
you need to specify the correct version of python to use for each programme.
For example, I need python 3.7 for miniconda, but mendeleydesktop claims for trouble with this version:

also problem with _posixsubproces and its location

so instead of run the program in a phyton enviroment only I use python2.7, and it solve the problem.
Hope it helps.
Cheers,
Flor